# What's the quickest way to check the size of an IEnumerable is greater than some given value?

Tags: c#, .net, count, ienumerable

I know that you can use `enumerable.Any()` instead of `enumerable.Count()` to check if the collection has anything in it efficiently.

Is there an equivalent to check the size is at least any larger size?

For example, how would I efficiently do `enumerable.Count() > 3`.

Comment: `Count()` is smart enough to use efficient methods already for some types.  Such as `List<T>.Count`.

Comment: You could maybe use `ElemantAtOrDefault` and do a null check but I would say using `Count` is the better option. Potential improvements in speed (haven't tested myself) are probably in the fractionally small amounts of time range, and at that point code readability should be the goal of your decision.

Comment: [morelinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) has [AtLeast](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#atleast).

Comment: You can do `enumerable.Skip(size).Any()` to avoid iterating the entire thing if the underlying type doesn't have a `Count` property it can use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most efficient approach will unfortunately depend on the implementation. It's a leaky abstraction at that point.

If you're using a `List<T>` or similar, using `Count()` will be fastest. But for any lazily-evaluated sequence, that will evaluate the *whole sequence*.

For a lazily-evaluated sequence, using `enumerable.Skip(3).Any()` will be more efficient, because it can stop once it's found the fourth element. That's all you need to know about; you don't care about the actual size.

Using the `Skip()`/`Any()` approach will be slightly less efficient than using `Count()` for some collections - but could be *much* more efficient for large lazy sequences. (It will also work even for infinite sequences, which `Count()` wouldn't.)

The difference in efficiency for lists will depend on how many items you're skipping, of course - if you need to see whether there are "at least a million" items then using `Count()` would be *much* more efficient for a list.

Sorry not to have an easy answer for you. If you really need this to be optimal in every case, you could perform the same kinds of optimization that the `Count()` method does. Something like this:

```cs
// FIXME: This name is horrible! Note that you'd call it with 4 in your case,
// as it's inclusive of minCount.
// Note this assumes C# 8 and its lovely switch expression support.
// It could be written with if/else etc of course.
public static bool HasAtMinElements<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int minCount) =>
    source switch
    {
        null => throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source)),
        ICollection<TSource> coll => coll.Count >= minCount,
        ICollection coll => coll.Count >= minCount,
        _ => source.Skip(minCount - 1).Any();
    }
```

That's annoying though :( Note that it doesn't optimize `IIListProvider<T>` like the [real `Count()` method does](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Count.cs#L12), either - because that's internal.

Comment: It also depends. List, i.e., supports Count() as super fast implementation, but NOT Count() on a Where (). Here you are stuck with Count () or Any () - Any being insuitable for anything except > 0, Count being possibly slower. Skip(x).Any() is a quite good compromise. YOu can not optimize that out - particualrly when filtering - but it means any execution can stop once the result is done, without returning an accurate count.

Comment: @TomTom: Indeed - whereas calling `Select()` on a list still doesn't let you take the count of the result, even though it'll be the same as it was before :( I'm sure a heavily optimized LINQ is feasible, but tricky to achieve cleanly.

Answer (score -2):

[Enumerable.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8) Method is the Microsoft's recommended way to return the number of elements in a sequence, which is what you are already doing and it is the best option as far as I see.

Comment: Actually it is not as per Jon. To see if there are X or more elements in - counting all may take too much time ;)

Comment: Fair enough. Always happy to be corrected by the legend Jon Skeet, hence the upvote for your comment TomTom.